# Nutch IllegalArgumentException: Row length 41221 is > 32767

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase, nutch

I have added a set of seeds to crawl using this command

./bin/crawl /largeSeeds 1 http://localhost:8983/solr/ddcd 4

For first iteration all of the commands(inject, generate, fetch, parse, update-table, Indexer & delete duplicates.) got executed successfully.
For second iteration, "CrawlDB update" command got failed (please see error log for reference), because of failure of this command the whole process gets terminated.

Software stack is nutch-branch-2.3.1, gora-hbase 0.6.1 Hadoop 2.5.2, hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2

```
16/01/20 02:45:19 INFO parse.ParserJob: ParserJob: finished at 2016-01-20 02:45:19, time elapsed: 00:06:57
CrawlDB update for 1
/usr/share/searchEngine/nutch-branch-2.3.1/runtime/deploy/bin/nutch updatedb -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.compress.map.output=true 1453230757-13191 -crawlId 1
16/01/20 02:45:27 INFO crawl.DbUpdaterJob: DbUpdaterJob: starting at 2016-01-20 02:45:27
16/01/20 02:45:27 INFO crawl.DbUpdaterJob: DbUpdaterJob: batchId: 1453230757-13191
16/01/20 02:45:27 INFO plugin.PluginRepository: Plugins: looking in: /tmp/hadoop-root/hadoop-unjar5654418190157422003/classes/plugins
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository: Plugin Auto-activation mode: [true]
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository: Registered Plugins:
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     HTTP Framework (lib-http)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Html Parse Plug-in (parse-html)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     MetaTags (parse-metatags)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     the nutch core extension points (nutch-extensionpoints)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Basic Indexing Filter (index-basic)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     XML Libraries (lib-xml)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Anchor Indexing Filter (index-anchor)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Basic URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-basic)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Language Identification Parser/Filter (language-identifier)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Metadata Indexing Filter (index-metadata)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     CyberNeko HTML Parser (lib-nekohtml)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Subcollection indexing and query filter (subcollection)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     SOLRIndexWriter (indexer-solr)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Rel-Tag microformat Parser/Indexer/Querier (microformats-reltag)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Http / Https Protocol Plug-in (protocol-httpclient)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     JavaScript Parser (parse-js)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Tika Parser Plug-in (parse-tika)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Top Level Domain Plugin (tld)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Regex URL Filter Framework (lib-regex-filter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Regex URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-regex)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Link Analysis Scoring Plug-in (scoring-link)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     OPIC Scoring Plug-in (scoring-opic)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     More Indexing Filter (index-more)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Http Protocol Plug-in (protocol-http)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Creative Commons Plugins (creativecommons)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository: Registered Extension-Points:
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Parse Filter (org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseFilter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Index Cleaning Filter (org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexCleaningFilter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Content Parser (org.apache.nutch.parse.Parser)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch URL Filter (org.apache.nutch.net.URLFilter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Scoring (org.apache.nutch.scoring.ScoringFilter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch URL Normalizer (org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizer)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Protocol (org.apache.nutch.protocol.Protocol)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Index Writer (org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriter)
16/01/20 02:45:28 INFO plugin.PluginRepository:     Nutch Indexing Filter (org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingFilter)
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x60a2630a connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=cism479
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_65
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
16/01/20 02:45:29 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_65/jre
16/01/20 02:45:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
16/01/20 02:45:35 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/01/20 02:45:36 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1453210838763_0011
16/01/20 02:45:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1453210838763_0011
16/01/20 02:45:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://cism479:8088/proxy/application_1453210838763_0011/
16/01/20 02:45:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1453210838763_0011
16/01/20 02:45:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1453210838763_0011 running in uber mode : false
16/01/20 02:45:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/01/20 02:47:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
16/01/20 02:47:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/01/20 02:48:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 0%
16/01/20 02:48:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/01/20 02:48:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 31%
16/01/20 02:48:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 33%
16/01/20 02:50:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 34%
16/01/20 03:01:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 35%
16/01/20 03:11:58 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 36%
16/01/20 03:22:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 37%
16/01/20 03:24:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 50%
16/01/20 03:24:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 82%
16/01/20 03:24:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 83%
16/01/20 03:26:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 84%
16/01/20 03:37:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
16/01/20 03:39:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1453210838763_0011_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row length 41221 is > 32767
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get.<init>(Get.java:89)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:208)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:79)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:56)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

16/01/20 03:39:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 50%
16/01/20 03:39:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 82%
16/01/20 03:39:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 83%
16/01/20 03:41:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 84%
16/01/20 03:53:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
16/01/20 03:55:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1453210838763_0011_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row length 41221 is > 32767
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get.<init>(Get.java:89)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:208)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:79)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:56)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

16/01/20 03:55:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 50%
16/01/20 03:56:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 83%
16/01/20 03:58:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 84%
16/01/20 04:10:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
16/01/20 04:12:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1453210838763_0011_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row length 41221 is > 32767
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation.checkRow(Mutation.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get.<init>(Get.java:89)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:208)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.get(HBaseStore.java:79)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:156)
    at org.apache.gora.store.impl.DataStoreBase.get(DataStoreBase.java:56)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdateReducer.reduce(DbUpdateReducer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

16/01/20 04:12:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 50%
16/01/20 04:12:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 82%
16/01/20 04:12:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 83%
16/01/20 04:14:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 84%
16/01/20 04:26:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
16/01/20 04:29:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/01/20 04:29:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1453210838763_0011 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1453210838763_0011_r_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1

16/01/20 04:29:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=38378343
        FILE: Number of bytes written=115957636
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=2382
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=2
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters
        Failed reduce tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=5
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=789909
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=30215090
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=263303
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=6043018
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=263303
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=6043018
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=808866816
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=30940252160
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=49929
        Map output records=1777904
        Map output bytes=382773368
        Map output materialized bytes=77228942
        Input split bytes=2382
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=754170
        Reduce shuffle bytes=38318183
        Reduce input records=881156
        Reduce output records=754170
        Spilled Records=2659060
        Shuffled Maps =2
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=2
        GC time elapsed (ms)=17993
        CPU time spent (ms)=819690
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=4080136192
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=15234293760
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=4149739520
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters
        Bytes Written=0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=[1]update-table, jobid=job_1453210838763_0011
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.run(DbUpdaterJob.java:111)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.updateTable(DbUpdaterJob.java:140)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.run(DbUpdaterJob.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DbUpdaterJob.main(DbUpdaterJob.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Error running:
  /usr/share/searchEngine/nutch-branch-2.3.1/runtime/deploy/bin/nutch updatedb -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D mapred.compress.map.output=true 1453230757-13191 -crawlId 1
Failed with exit value 1.
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with the same techno.

I resolved this by changing the file HConstants.java in the hbase-common-0.98.17-hadoop2.jar (in nutch : nutch/build/lib and in hbase : /hbase/lib).

I removed this line :

```
public static final short MAX_ROW_LENGTH = Short.MAX_VALUE;
```

And added this line :

```
public static final long MAX_ROW_LENGTH = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Now, it works like a charm.

Please say me if it's running for you too or if you need help for the jar.

Comment: i see, In my case I got it fixed by skipping the URLs by activating the "urlfilter-regex" plugin and adding this code to regex-urlfilter.txt file in nutch.  :

`# skip URLs longer than 1024 characters
-^.{1024,}$`

Thanks for the workaround @jérémie

Comment: I will try this. It's better to avoid the big urls. :)

Comment: In fact my problem is different. It's when the nutch "Flushing the datastore after 40000 records". Because the number of records is more than 32767.

Comment: I tried modifying the files in hbase source and then build the source, after replaced the jars in Nutch, but I encountered the same error. any thoughts ?

Comment: In fact, when we build the nutch repository, the "real" version is downloaded... and the files apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar and apache-nutch-2.3.1.job have the bad file, only these files are used. If you want try this tricks, you have to modify the jars files inside.  But after some investigations, it seems that limit the url size like you suggested was enough for me. Because my problem was not linked to the flushing size strangely...

Comment: Thanks for insights @jérémie . I solved it in a tricky manner, here are the steps I followed, #1) Modified the source file. #2) Compile the source. #3) Copy the modified jars from the newly compiled source to binary. #4) cleanup the temp data and restarted hbase. Now its working perfectly. Hope this solution will help anyone else.